# Как изменять сообщение бота несколько раз подряд?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Я пытаюсь создать бота с использованием библиотеки pyTelegramBotAPI который при запуске бота выводила текст "x=0" с Inline кнопкой "+1", при нажатии которой тексте будет меняться на "x=1" и т.д. при дальнейших нажатиях.

Вот сам код:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot("6967578479:AAHAq-E5xM7K96kYkkV---5BrOkH0yyX1bM")
x=0

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="+1", callback_data="+1")
    keyboard.row(button)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"x={x}.", reply_markup=keyboard)

    @bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda callback: True)
    def callback_messange(callback):
        if callback.data == "+1":
            x=+1
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback.message.chat.id,text= f"x={x}.",message_id=message.message_id+1,reply_markup=keyboard)

bot.infinity_polling()
```

Но при 2 нажатии выдает ошибку:

telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: message is not modified: specified new message content and reply markup are exactly the same as a current content and reply markup of the message

Comment: Где вы такой гениальный способ изменения id сообщения подсмотрели? 

Comment: Где где, в инете

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша проблема была в том, что Вы не проверяли значение **x**. Вы объявили **x** в глобальной области видимости и при каждом нажатии кнопки, он возвращал своё значение на 0 и затем прибавлял 1.

А так, как он уже был равен 1, после первого нажатия кнопки, то бот пытается изменить сообщение *x=1* на точно такое же - *x=1*, из-за этого и ошибка.

В данном способе, я указал x=0 просто первоначальной строкой, а затем при каждом нажатии кнопки, бот берёт значение из текста сообщения, находит там значение x, делает из него тип данных int и прибавляет к нему 1, а затем изменяет сообщение на прибавленное значение. И так после каждого нажатия кнопки.

**! Важно:** стоит написать свой алгоритм распознавания текущего значения **x**, после каждого нажатия кнопки. Мой способ лишь для примера, он ищет значение по разделению строки на список строк, если между частями есть знак равно (=).

Но если добавить туда текст, точку в конце или что-то ещё, всё сломается. Можете написать регулярное выражение или найти другой способ распознания.

Также, если **x** будет в глобальной области видимости, то это повлияет на всех пользователей бота сразу.

```py
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="-1", callback_data="-1")
    button2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="+1", callback_data="+1")

    keyboard.row(button1, button2)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"x=0", reply_markup=keyboard)

    @bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda callback: True)
    def callback_messange(callback):
        text = callback.message.text # текст сообщения, на котором нажата была кнопка;
        x_form = text.split("=") # разделяем строку на значения до и после знака равно и получаем формат: ['x', '0'];
        x_value = x_form[1] # обращаемся к второму элементу списка, где будет значение x;

        if callback.data == "+1":
            x = int(x_value) + 1 # делаем  строку значения числом и прибавляем 1;
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback.message.chat.id, message_id=callback.message.id, text= f"x={x}", reply_markup=keyboard)

        if callback.data == "-1":
            x = int(x_value) - 1 # делаем  строку значения числом и отнимаем 1;
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback.message.chat.id, message_id=callback.message.id, text= f"x={x}", reply_markup=keyboard)

bot.infinity_polling()
```

**upd:** заметил, что у Вы странно берёте id сообщения, решил поправить.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, вы не правильно получаете id своего сообщения, отсюда и ошибки. Вот вам небольшой пример:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Счет: 0", callback_data="increment")
    keyboard.add(button)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Счет: 0', reply_markup=keyboard)

# Обработчик нажатия
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == "increment")
def increment_callback(call):
    # Получаем текущее значение счетчика из текста калбэка
    count = int(call.message.text.split(":")[1].strip()) + 1
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f"Счет: {count}", callback_data="increment")
    keyboard.add(button)
    # Изменяем текст существующего сообщения с обновленным счетчиком и кнопкой, но наверное лучше удалять и отправлять новое сообщение
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text=f'Счет: {count}',
                          reply_markup=keyboard)

bot.polling()
```